# Delegate ivars as pointers

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, delegates

I've been looking at my code and I usually declare my delegate ivars as pointers like this:

```
__weak NSObject <ViewControllerDelegate> *delegate;
```

I noticed Apple declares them like this in their example code:

```
__weak id <ViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

What's the difference between using NSObject or id?

Also what's the difference between using * to declare as pointer, as using the delegate doesn't seem to change on wether or not it's a pointer,

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`id` is really `pointer to some random object`.

So, there is no difference between `id` and `NSObject*` in terms of whether or not you have a pointer.

There is a big difference otherwise.

`id <MyDelegateP> delegate` means `delegate` *is a pointer to some object that is only guaranteed to implement the methods in `MyDelegateP`protocol, no more no less*.

Whereas `NSObject <MyDelegateP>*` means `delegate` *is a pointer to some object that is an instance of `NSObject` (or subclass) and also implements  all methods in the `MyDelegateP` protocol*.

These days, most protocols are declared as inheriting from the `<NSObject>` protocol.

```
@protocol MyDelegateP <NSObject>
@end
```

Since the `<NSObject>` protocol declares basic services like hashing, memory management, and introspection (and it is pretty much impossible to work with classes that don't inherit from `NSObject`) doing this results in a delegate that can be put into collections, can be introspected for method implementation (for optional methods), etc...

---

So, do this:

```
 @protocol ViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
 ...
 @end
```

Then this:

```
__weak id <ViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

But there is nothing wrong with this (it adds a few methods that aren't in the NSObject protocol and is slightly redundant, but still OK):

```
__weak NSObject <ViewControllerDelegate> *delegate;
```

Comment: Great answer! So the way i'm declaring is OK then? I can mark your answer as correct as soon as 10 mins have elapsed:)

Comment: @JohnWoods yes, it's fine. i specify the type as well. i do it by convention. sometimes that is `NSObject` (which doesn't mean much, as bbum mentioned), but the type is always specified. often, the type is more specific than `NSObject`. this allows the compiler to kick in and save you from invalid assignments to the variable. it can also help the compiler match methods to an object if you use anything outside of the protocol's declarations. it's just a way to keep type safety in your programs (in some cases, the type adds nothing).

Comment: @justin With `id <Protocol> obj`, the compiler will complain about any method invocation on `obj` that is *not in Protocol*.   It is actually a very constrained type declaration vs. plain `id`.   Which is weird.

Comment: @bbum good point. the implication of the benefit wrt method matching: it kicks in by saving one from (unnecessary) explicit casting to the type when one wants to deviate from the methods declared in the protocol. in ARC, that's an error. in MRC, that can slip past unnoticed (e.g. depending on enabled warnings and how closely one reviews them). it can also help when you try to use the object; if its interface is not visible then another selector could be matched (in MRC). …

Comment: …preserving the underlying type is usually unnecessary, it's pointed out multiple bugs in my code over the years, so i stick with it. although conventional, i regard using `id<>` as a programmer's choice to erase the type (without a good reason).

Comment: I absolutely stick with `id <Protocol>` because of the precision.  I just always make my protocols inherit, at least, from `<NSObject>`.